# A bookmarklet-friendly Javascript that grabs source?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

So,

I'm trying to build a simple bookmarklet that does a whole bunch of stuff based upon the source code (Which, itself, contains javascript.

Essentially, it's taking a number of bits of data from source which it grabs and and finds using regex queries and then manipulates.

I've got everything beyond the grabbing the source code... I just need some help figuring out the source bit.

So, what do I need to do to take the source code of the page I'm currently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get the object (with something like document.getElementById()), you can try using .innerHTML

For example

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="box">I want the code for this <span>html</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The javascript would run something like this

```
var data=document.getElementById('box').innerHTML;
```

Here's a demo in JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/LW2VH/

Answer (score 2):

`document.documentElement.innerHTML` will get you everything except the `<html>` tag itself and the `<doctype>`.  But, this may not be the actual source code, as the html may have changed by some script.  It may be better to get the source code via Ajax:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", location.href, false);
xhr.send();
var source = xhr.responseText;
```